# Conditionals inside the link_to description in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, link-to

I have a link_to messages

```
<%= link_to "Messages (#{Messages.count})", messages_path %>
```

but if the count is 0 I'd like to remove the (0).

How do I incorporate this 'If condition' inside the link_to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options, but this one should work in this case:

```
link_to "Messages #{Messages.count > 0 ? '(%d)' : ''}" % Messages.count, messages_path
```

For more sophisticated logic than this you'd want to make a helper method:

```
link_to label_with_optional_counter("Messages", Messages.count), messages_path
```

You define that method in the appropriate helper module:

```
def label_with_optional_counter(label, count)
  "%s #{count > 0 ? '(%d)' : ''}" % [ label, count ]
end
```

Comment: what is the % notation called?

Comment: Generally `%` means *modulo* as in `15 % 10` equals `5`, but in this case `String#%` is actually a more succinct way of using [`sprintf`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf). This sort of thing works almost exactly the same way in Python, too.